# How do i get elements from a file and read them to a list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

What i am trying to do is read from a file, and insert the content from a file into a list in python 3. the file should look like this:

```
♥A
♣A
♥Q
♠Q
```

and the result i am expecting when i read from the file is that  when i print the specific list is that it shows up like this

```
['♥A', '♣A', '♥Q', '♠Q']
```

How would i go about solving this?

And i have tried multiple solutions for this, like using for loops, but i dont understand how to do this

Comment: open --> read --> split --> success!

Comment: I think this one is separate because of the special characters, but the title is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `open` function.

```py
f = open("file.txt", "r")

l = list()

for line in f:
    l.append(line)

f.close()

print(l)
```

Comment: [Why not w3schools.com?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com)

Comment: when i do this, it shows up like this ``` [b'\xe2\x99\xa3Q\n', b'\xe2\x99\xa6J\n', b'\xe2\x99\xa310\n', b'\xe2\x99\xa67\n'] ```

Comment: @Sayse : they do not include close() to close the file after openning it :D

Comment: @RoaldAndreKvarv likely because they're special characters that aren't naturally supported by Python.

Comment: @Corsaka how would i go about making them valid tho? like the unicode symbols

Comment: @RoaldAndreKvarv Append `.decode('utf8')` to `open()`.

Comment: Don't print the list representation but print the single items.

Comment: @Sayse Indeed, w3schools isn't the best tutorial website, yet one of the most accessible for beginners.

Comment: @Donshel - I was just making you aware of why generally they're never used as a reference on [so].